# Where to start studying about HTM?

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, neural-networks, neural-computing, boltzmann-machine

I am looking for references (pedagogic and beginner friendly!) to these two topics,

- hierarchical temporal memory algorithms applied to deep planning problems
- (multi-layer) neural networks trained via SGD (after some bottom-up pre-learning using autoassociator / RBM algorithms)

Can someone help with a reference (hopefully online!) which can get me started?

It would be best I could find some course-notes.

Comment: Where have you looked? Have you googled and checked the canonical textbooks?

Comment: @Raphael I am completely new to the subject and hence I have no clue what are the canonical textbooks. I googled around and that led me to Wiki kind of links. I found some MIT-OCW course-notes which seem to be talking of related stuff but thats as far as it looks to a novice!

Comment: Well, then start with that! Taking a MOOC is probably a very good way to get started. Canonical textbooks you can find by checking literature recommendations of introductory courses, just roam college websites!

Comment: @Raphael Can you link to some introductory courses you might know of which talks of these subjects?